# Gravity differences on asteroid with an O'Neill cylinder

Tags: science-based, space-constructs, asteroids

In my story there is something akin to an [Island Three O'Neill cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder) buried vertically into the side of the asteroid [Vesta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_Vesta).  It is 5 miles across and 20 miles long.  The station is buried but is spun up inside of a cylindrical shell carved out of the asteroid. The whole of Vesta does not need to be spun. The station is buried for two purposes: to protect from cosmic radiation and to give better access to the miners.

Vesta's gravity is about 0.25 m/s^2 which (I think) is around 0.03G. For things to feel like 1G inside, the cylinder should produce 0.9995G artificially.

Now, (if I'm doing the math right) using arctan(0.03/0.9995) the inside of the cylinder would feel like it has a 1.72° slope to it, which doesn't seem like much, but...

1. Would this feel like a hill?  Would walking far surface-ward wear you out faster than?  Could you throw a ball further "downhill" at this angle?  Or would it not even feel any different?
2. Would it make sense to build terraces periodically to level things out?
3. Would this noticeably affect air pressure or water flow across the gradient of the cylinder?

I'm trying to feel out if this would even be worth mentioning my story, or if the effect is so negligible that it wouldn't.

Comment: Long time no see, Sam!  Welcome back!  I'm not much of an orbital mechanic, so could you explain where the arctan(a/(1-a)) comes from?  What's its purpose?

Comment: How can the O'Neill cylinder generate gravity if it is buried and cannot rotate?

Comment: What is the 'Island Three' thinf about? I cannot find anything on the quick neither in the linked resource nor via google

Comment: It's worth noting that an O'Neill cylinder's spin "gravity" pushes things to the outside of the cylinder, whereas the asteroid's true gravity pulls things to the center. You would actually want to have slightly *more* spin in order to get precisely 1g acceleration.

Comment: A slope of 1.72° comes to 3 in 100. It would definitely feel like hill. Find a road nearby marked 3% and see how it feels. What's keeping you from making the inside walls of the cylinder into a series of suitably sloped pieces so that the combined gravitation and centrifugal force pressed exactly perpendicular on the floors? (Like this: `^^^^`.) Air pressure does not have much relationship with the apparent gravitational acceleration; on the other hand, water definitely flows downhill.

Comment: This is a good question, but i have to ask, why bury the cylinder into the asteroid at all? doing so means you'd need to spin the entire asteroid to generate the centrifugal force needed by the cylinder. if its so you can easily mine the asteroid, then surely having the cylinder matching orbits with Vesta and send mining parties onto and off of the asteroid would be a a lot more efficient then spinning the entire thing?

Comment: @JBH thanks! Life has been busy. My idea using arctan was for computing the perceived angle. There is an outward force of 1G made by the artificial gravity and then another force perpendicular to that caused by the natural gravity.

Comment: @L.Dutch great question. It spins inside a shell see edit.

Comment: @BladeWraith no need to spin up the asteroid, the station spins in a cylindrical shell. See edit.

Comment: @AlexP Right! I had already been thinking how those would feel and called the terraces, i.e multiple sloped pieces.

Comment: @Cadence Vesta is quite a large asteroid and even though the station is 20 miles long the majority of the natural gravity should pull things towards the deepest part of the station.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Island Three is just the largest of O’Neill’s designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a force toward the more-or-less center of Vesta of 0.03g and a perpendicular force of 0.9995g.  Earth experiences [magnitude variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Variation_in_magnitude) of up to 0.7% and Vesta's gravity represents 3%.  I'm not sure people would feel this that all, but it is "sideways," which would be odd.  Let's run with it.

OK (it's been a while since I did inclined plane physics, so I might be wrong)...

Potential Energy = mgd sin(θ)

- m = mass
- g = gravity constant
- θ = angle of the hill
- d = distance travelled (we're going to assume "1")

At 0° the contribution due to the hill is 0 J.  We want a contribution equal to the affect of Vesta's gravity.  F= ma.

m(0.03g) = mg sin(θ)

0.03 = sin(θ)

θ = 1.72° (which you calculated! I'm on the right track.)

So, living in your environment means feeling like you're constantly walking up and down a 1.72° hill.  What's that like?

Well... that was a long and fancy way of saying you're stepping up 0.03 meters (30 cm) for every meter walked or just over an inch for every 3.28 feet walked.

It's almost nothing.  I doubt people would even notice it.  According to [this bicycling site](http://theclimbingcyclist.com/gradients-and-cycling-an-introduction/) a 3% grade (which this represents, rise/run*100 = 0.03/1*100 = 3%) is like riding your bike into the wind (of course, they don't tell you what wind...) but not considered much of a challenge to cyclists.

*OK, whether or not a 3% grade is an issue depends on what's happeneing.  For a person walking, it's likely not noticable.  For a car moving at 70mph, it represents a risk if a sharp turn occurs.  For a train, it's a big deal.  It really depends on how much mass is being moved.  As mass increases, the grade of the hill becomes more important (especially downhill) because the energy needed to overcome the grade increases with it.  A 3% grade won't cause my Toyota Prius to recharge.  I'm just sayin'*

Oooh.  You had more questions.  You can't "level things out" with terracing.  It may feel like you're living on the side of a 3% hill, but you actually aren't.  You can't change an angle to make the potential energy due to Vesta's gravity go away.  You can thank the need to spin your cyclinder for that.

It does mean that if you spill a glass of water, it's going to want to dribble in the direction of Vesta's core.  Remember, 3% isn't much.  If you spilled it on a big sheet of glass you'd see it move, but if you spilled it on concrete you probably wouldn't.

It will mean a slight increase in air pressure toward the center of Vesta.  But, once again, I doubt it would be noticable.

Comment: Hmm. I don’t understand why the terraces idea wouldn’t work. If the station never stops spinning wouldn’t the net force on a 1.72 degree hill be the same as pointing down, or is there something about the spin that makes it different?

Comment: Remember that there is no hill.  On earth, the two forces (gravity and the effect of the hill) are nearly parallel.  In your case, the two forces are perpendicular: 90°-1.72° = 88.28°  By terracing to get rid of the Vesta gravity effect you've caused your people to walk up and down hills equal to a 100% grade.  Vesta has the *effect* of living on a hill ... but there is no hill.  You could turn your cylinder so that it's lying on the surface rather than embedded into the asteroid, but the effect is to cause a 3% variance due to the spin v. Vesta.

Comment: Of course, if the cylinder is lying on the surface, you could adjust the spin so the effect was ±1.5% Earth-norm, which might be easier to absorb/ignore - if your story can handle the shift.

Comment: Trying to get my head around this... Ok, so imagine you're standing inside this station.  If you lay a 1 meter level on the ground oriented "surface" to "core", the bubble will shift towards the surface in a way that would look like a 3% grade on earth.  Right?  If that's true, if you place a 3cm block of wood under the "core" side of your 1m level, what would happen to the bubble?

Comment: If you put a level on the floor (wall) of your cylinder, the perpendicular force of Vesta will pull the bubble off-center toward the center of Vesta.  But remember, you're not dealing with one force and a bubble that's mechanically off-angle. You're dealing with two forces.  The second force (Vesta) will always pull against the bubble no matter what angle it's at (zeroing out only at 90°). And as you adjust that angle in your attempt, you're making the bubble off-angle to the much larger first force of your spin. A mechanical solution doesn't work because it's not a mechanical problem.

Comment: Oh, and "zeroing out only at 90°" only refers to the effect on the bubble due to Vesta.  In reality, the bubble will be slammed against the side closest to the wall due to the spin.

Comment: So there is the force from the spin pulling the bubble towards the wall, and most of Vesta below pulling it downwards, and if you precariously balance that bubble between those two forces, the angle will be 88.28°?  Is that it?  (Sorry for being so dense here...)

Comment: There is no orientation of the bubble that will cancel the consequence of vesta's gravity.  My point with the 88.28° number is that if you rotate the level such that the bubble is balanced against the Vesta gravity, the result is a terrace so steep compared to the cylinder gravity that people will feel like they're hiking up and down a 100% grade.  You can't cancel out one of two perpendicular forces with a mechanical solution.  The problem is not mechanical.  It has the *effect* of an inclined plane, but it is *not* an inclined plane.  The only solution is 0.03g in the opposite direction.

Comment: OK, that's a good way of saying it.  Terracing solves the problem of being out of balance with one force vector.  The goal is to have a floor perpendicular to the one force vector.  Your problem is you have two vectors... but only one floor.  Changing the pitch of the floor to balance one vector puts you out of balance for the other (making the problem worse).  One solution is a mass equal to Vesta's such that you have a third force, one that cancels out the other, leaving you with one force vector.  Your other option is to find a local minima balancing the two forces.  You already have that.

Comment: Terracing to any extent pulls you away from the local minima.  Thus, no terracing.  People will get used to the *feel* of walking up and down a shallow hill, but there is no hill and no (practical) way to make things better.

Comment: I’ve got it. Thanks JBH. It’s counterintuitive for an Earth dweller like myself but it makes sense now. And it might make for some interesting storytelling.